# Microsoft Azure DDoS protection alert not recevied

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-monitoring, azure-security, azure-ddos

I have implemented Azure DDos with standard(paid) and also setup alert. But I get 45,000 attack on my server and did not received any alert related to it. Can anyone tell where I have done any mistake or left configuration related to DDos.
Let me clear what configure I have made so far:-

- Configure **DDos Protection Plan**
- Turn **Standard**
- Also configure **Diagnostic settings** related to DDos on its **IP**
- Setup alert on **Azure Monitor** with **Sev-1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike **DDoS Protection Basic**, the **DDoS Protection Standard** supports **Metrics & alerts** and hence  allows user for configuration of alerts for any of the Azure Monitor metrics that DDoS Protection uses and thus Azure DDoS Protection Standard service helps in protection based on telemetry data from Azure Monitor Service.

As part of cofiguration steps, once the DDoS protection plan is created and selected, you may need to create an alert rule in Azure monitor so that notifications are sent if there is a DDoS attack.

For receiving email alerts, you need to configure an email alert for the preferred metric using “Click to add an alert”. Here, the metric of interest is “Under DDoS attack or not”. Set the Metric for “Under DDoS attack or not” and alert logic “Condition” to “Greater than” zero (0) and you will receive alert email while on attack. Also, you need to ensure filling in appropriate threshold values , evaluation details as per your alert requirement for getting the alerts coupled with filling in email details in action group.

Comment: Thank you, for your help.
but still I don't get any alert although I am getting hit by malicious IP and botnet.
No alert triggered